# XPath result type is NodeSet rather than string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, return-type, xpath-2.0

I am using the WmHelp.XPath2 library to evaluate user xpath 2.0 queries that are specificed in configuration, but I need the XPath to return a string.

```
fn:string(//*:Identity/*:User/*:Name/text())
```

example xml below (there is custom namespaces, which is why the wildcards have been used in the xpath query):

```
<RootElement>
  <Identity>
    <User>
      <Name>username</Name>
    </User>
  </Identity>
.....
```

The XPath will evaluate fine, but I need it to evaluate to a string and not NodeSet. My code looks like below:

```
XPath2Expression uname_lookup = XPath2Expression.Compile(_emailToSource);

if (uname_lookup.ReturnType != XPath2ResultType.String)
{
      throw new ApplicationException("USERNAME_LOOKUP XPath query has invalid return type. Must have a return type of string.");
}
string username = (string)navigator.XPath2Evaluate(uname_lookup);
```

I am getting the exception thrown every time. I realise there may be an issues with the XPath2ResultType enum definition with Navigator and String being assigned the same value, but does anyone know a way to get my xpath to evaluate to a string every time.

```
namespace Wmhelp.XPath2
{
    public enum XPath2ResultType
    {
        Number = 0,
        Navigator = 1,
        String = 1,
        Boolean = 2,
        NodeSet = 3,
        Any = 5,
        Error = 6,
        DateTime = 7,
        Duration = 8,
        AnyUri = 9,
        QName = 10,
        Other = 11,
    }
}
```

Comment: That enum is distinctly worrying. Have you tried just using the `NodeSet` returned, and getting the first result? This sounds like a bug in the library, to be honest - I would suggest filing a bug in the library (as well as hopefully seeing someone with more experience with it answering here).

Comment: I didn't even know you were allowed to have multiple Enum members with the same underlying values...

Comment: Apparently the issue is also in Microsofts System.Xml.XPath library. Found this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132649/xpathresulttype-definition-error

Comment: Jon, I think that looks like my only option at the moment, Thanks